# Can't find the output to terminal option anymore in Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

This option used to be available on previous version Xcode, has it been removed or changed to a location I can't find?

> Found in Products > Schemes > Manage Schemes > [select one] Edit
>   /Run/Options

[image]

Comment: I noticed the option is there in the same location for Mac projects but is missing for iOS projects so I doubt it's been moved.

Comment: Thanks, that may be that it's only available for Mac project

Answer (score 0):

The option is only available for macOS applications.
I checked it.